# Similarity of Connection pooling in ADO.NET and Throttling in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf, ado.net

can someone explain me that connection pooling in ADO.Net and Throttling in WCF is somewhat same.

Answer (score 1):

They only seem similar.

[SQL Connection Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is about reusing.

> Connecting to a database server typically consists of several
>   time-consuming steps. A physical channel such as a socket or a named
>   pipe must be established, the initial handshake with the server must
>   occur, the connection string information must be parsed, the
>   connection must be authenticated by the server, checks must be run for
>   enlisting in the current transaction, and so on.
>
> In practice, most applications use only one or a few different
>   configurations for connections. This means that during application
>   execution, many identical connections will be repeatedly opened and
>   closed. **To minimize the cost of opening connections, ADO.NET uses an
>   optimization technique called connection pooling.**
>
> Connection pooling reduces the number of times that new connections
>   must be opened. The pooler maintains ownership of the physical connection. It manages 
>   connections by keeping alive a set of active connections for each
>   given connection configuration.  Whenever a user calls Open on a connection, the pooler 
>   looks for an available connection in the pool. If a pooled connection
>   is available, it returns it to the caller instead of opening a new
>   connection.

[WCF Throttling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735114%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is about limiting how many service instances or sessions are created at the application level.

[The main purpose for the throttling settings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx?Redirected=true) can be classified into the following two aspects:

> 1. **Controlled resource usage**: With the throttling of concurrent
>      execution, the usage of resources such as memory or threads can be
>      limited to a reasonable level so that the system works well without
>      hitting reliability issues.
> 2. **Balanced performance load**:
>      Systems always work in a balanced way when the load is controlled.
>      If there are too much concurrent execution happening, a lot of
>      contention and bookkeeping would happen and thus it would hurt the
>      performance of the system.

Two different concepts serving two different purposes.